# Copying files from a Rails plugin into the application upon plugin install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

When someone installs this plugin, I would like a file to be copied into the config/initializers directory of the app.  I could do this in install.rb by copying a template file that resides somewhere in the plugin.  Another option would be to require the user to run a generator after install.  I know rspec-rails makes you run a generator after you install it, is that the recommended behavior?

And is there anything wrong with copying files into the application in install.rb?

Thanks!

Lou

Comment: I think is ok. Restful auth. generates into lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the user need to manually tweak the file?  If so, then I would use a generator with parameters.  If not, I would prefer that you do it with install.rb.  My $.02

Comment: No tweaking required.  $.02 appreciated.